# Exporting multiple images from a multipage pdf

Tags: pdf, export, jpg

I have a client who insists on sending me images in pdf form which I have to extract, resize and upload to their website. I have been using Photoshop to manually crop out the images but im looking for a faster way.

The main problem is there are 2-4 images per page in the pdf and I can easily export a whole page as a jpg but I cannot figure out how to export all of these images as separate jpgs.

I have Adobe Acrobat Pro DC 2015

Im really looking for a batch system that allows me to extract all the images at once.

EDIT: I know the ideal thing would be to instruct the client to send us jpgs, however, I am looking into this export pdf possibility as well. Please only respond if you have any information on exporting multiple images from a single pdf page using Acrobat DC. Thank you.

Comment: Is there a reason why the client is sending the images in PDF format, especially multiple images on a PDF? Have you tried communicating to the client that you just need the images in JPG format in separate files? Do you know if the PDFs are flattened?

Comment: Client is stubborn and insistent that this is the only way they can send them, although we are trying to have them send us jpgs. I do not know if it is flattened, when i go to edit in Acrobat it says it scans the page for content and then I can move the images individually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you AndrewH for the information, your instructions helped me find what I was looking for. However in the most recent version of Acrobat Pro the location of this option has changed slightly. So I will provide screenshots for anyone else with the newest versions of Acrobat.

There is no tab named 'Document Processing' anymore. Instead this option is found under the 'Export PDF' tool. With your PDF open in Acrobat you can select the Export PDF tool on the right hand side where it is located with all your other tools.

[image: Export PDF tool in right sidebar]

When clicked it will open a fullscreen options page with a preview of your pdf. You must select 'Image' and then select which type of image you want to export. You can use the settings gear next to the image type to find advanced settings.

[image: Export PDF Image screen]

To export all images from an unflattened PDF you must select 'Export all images'. Then you can select a destination for your files and Acrobat will save all images in your pdf to the selected destination.

I hope this helps people with the newest versions of Acrobat who are not familiar with the older version enough to stumble through the new menus and options.

Thank you again AndrewH for the clear explanations that helped me find what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

1) This only works if your PDF is not flattened

Open your PDF in Adobe Acrobat Pro

Under Tools, open the Document Processing tab. If the tab is not there go to the dropdown icon on the top right and make sure it is checked.

[image: document processing]

In that tab select Export All Images.

2) If the PDF is flat, you can create slices in Photoshop and export that way.

3) Unless someone here gives a better answer you can relay to your client that to stay on schedule with the given project you will need the images in jpg format. They may concede to your demands if you phrase it that way.

Answer (score 0):

As stated above, this is dependent on the PDF not being flattened into one image.  You will also need Acrobat Pro for this.

Click on the image you want to export, it will highlight in blue.
Once it it highlighted, right-click on the image and you will have the option to "Save Image As".

This method will export the image as a .jpg at the original size of the placed file including any areas that might be masked off.

Comment: yes, however, I was looking for a way to export all of the 100+ images in 25+ pdf pages. This method only exports individual images and does not save me any time.

Comment: eew.  yeah, I can understand that.  I'm not familiar enough on if that is possible or not.  since you can do it for one, there might be an export all assets option.

Answer (score 0):

Old question I know....

**Don't use Acrobat, use Photoshop**

Drag the PDF to Photoshop.....

When the PDF options pop up, tick the `Images` option in the upper left corner of the pop up....

There are all your images, from all pages.

[image]

Shift-click to select multiple images then click `OK`. They will all open (as images) in Photoshop.

From there save/export them as needed, which can be done via an action if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Mac OS X then there are a couple of apps that do what you need.

1. [The Unarchiver](https://theunarchiver.com) (free)
2. [File Juicer](https://echoone.com/filejuicer/download) (demo, €14 for full version)

Drop a PDF on either of these and it will extract the text, images and any other contents in a lossless way.